# Change the style of a dynamically added div element when user clicks on the div or its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I am trying to change the styling of a specific div element that I .append() to the page when the user clicks on it or one of its child elements.  This is the JavaScript I have so far:

```
 var activeNote;

    $(".note").click(function () {
        activeNote = $(this);
        activeNote.css("border", "2px solid white");
    });

    $(".title, .reminder").click(function () {
        activeNote = $(this).parent();
        activeNote.css("border", "2px solid white");
    });
```

The String I append to the page:

```
"<div class='note'><input type='text' placeholder='Title...' class='title' /><textarea name='text1' class='reminder' cols='40' rows='2' placeholder='Note...'></textarea></div>";
```

A better way of looking at the string:

```
<div class="note">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Title..." class="title" />
     <textarea name="text1" class="reminder" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="Note..."></textarea>
</div>
```

Nothing extra happens when I add this code and click on the div element so something is wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Umm, is your question in your title? Your title should describe the question, not answer it.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you when you click on `.note` or either of its children, you want to make a change to `.note`?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I want to do.  Sorry for any confusion.  I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, using `this` inside an event handler always refers the element that is receiving the event. To act on `.note` when it or it's children are clicked you could use event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```js
 var activeNote;

    $("#note-container").on('click', '.note', function () {
        activeNote = $(this);
        activeNote.css("border", "2px solid white");
    });
```

```css
#note-container {
  background: #cef;
  padding: 1em;
}

.note {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="note-container">
  <div class="note">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Title..." class="title" />
       <textarea name="text1" class="reminder" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="Note..."></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.note` elements dynamically, you need to change the way you bind your events

From

```
$(".note").click(function () { ... });
$(".title, .reminder").click(function () { ... });
```

To

```
$(document).on('click', '.note', function () { ... });
$(document).on('click', '.title, .reminder', function () { ... })
```

This way, even elements inserted to the DOM *after* the event handler is defined will be subject to the event handler.

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: That's fantastic.  Thanks so much!